# Need help for complicated RestTemplate Body Object. How can I build this using RestTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, java-8, resttemplate

So i have an endpoint that requires a request body:

```
"email": {
    "body": {
      "template": {
        "data": {
          "name": "John Doe",
          "verificationDate": "11-12-2020"
        },
        "id": 1
      }
    },
    "subject": {
      "text": "Verification Email"
    },
    "to": [
      "test@example.com"
    ]
  }
```

Anybody have idea to build this on the RequestBody for RestTemplate?

Answer (score 0):

Building a complicated RequestBody is nothing different from building a simple one, except that you need more code. Just do what you have done when building the simplest request body. If you have any specific problem, tell me.